# Invalid value: Not in inclusive range error, But my listview.builder has itemcount property

Tags: flutter, dart

```
return Container(
           padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: lotteries.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
                            var lottery =
                                json.decode(lotteries[index].lotteryNumbers);
                            print(lottery);
                            return ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                              itemCount: lottery.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctex, int i) {
                                return GetBuilder<CartController>(
                                  init: CartController(),
                                  builder: (context) {
                                    return new GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        cartController.addItem(lottery[i]);
                                        lotteryController
                                            .toggleFavouriteStatus(i);
                                      },
                                      child: Container(Text("${lottery[i]}"))
```

I have two listviews but both of them have item count property. I am getting the not-in-inclusive range error. But I have specified the length for both my lists. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What type is `lotteries`? From your code, because you need `json.decode` to parse each of `lotteries`, I thinks its because `lotteries` is still in json format. You need to decode it first, then return it as a List, so you can get the count number.

Comment: As a friendly reminder, please user Reformat Code with 'dart format' so it's  more readable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you run out of values when iterating over an array or list. In the case of the ListView component missing the itemCount prop, the component attempts to continue to iterate but is unaware when to complete so it eventually continues on out of range (the length of the array).

You could also see this error after running a poorly set up for loop. For example:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    print(arr[i]);
}
```

This  code would result in a range error as well. The array has 4 items yet we attempt to iterate 5 times.
you can print  `itemCount: lotteries.length & itemCount: lottery.length`
if evrything is ok u can wait some delay in to call second lattery listbuilder.